# How to reverse a chain of characters?

Tags: fortran

I have to create a program that **reverses phrases**.

For example: when I write `hello guys`, I want `syug olleh`

This is what I have for the moment but I don't know how to reverse the characters in the board `phraseT`:

```
program reversing    
implicit none    
character(len=20),dimension(1:20)::phraseT    
character(len=20)::phrase,reverse    
integer::i,x


write(*,*)"write a phrase  :"    
read(*,'(a)')phrase    
x=len(trim(phrase))    
nomT(1:20)=" " 

do i=1,x    
nomT(i:i)=trim(phrase(i:i))    
end do

write(*,*)nomT    
end program reversing
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One simple way to do it ...

```
character(80) :: string = "Whatttt's up doc?"
character     :: temp
integer       :: i, length

write (*,*) string    ! Writes it out proper.
  length = len_trim(string) ! ignores trailing blanks. 
                            ! use len(string) to reverse those as well
  do i = 1, length/2
     temp = string(i:i)
     string(i:i) = string(length+1-i:length+1-i)
     string(length+1-i:length+1-i) = temp
  end do
write(*,*) string     ! Writes it out backwards.
end
```

Others will come up with more intelligent ones (and shorter) for sure.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a shorter way to do it:

```
forall (i=1:len(string)) string(i:i) = string(len(string)-i+1:len(string)-i+1)
```

It even saves a handful of bytes ! I'm not sure I'd suggest this was more intelligent though.

Comment: This one fails using flang from AMD AOCC or nvfortran from NVIDIA HPC SDK. I guess those are bugs in the compilers. The string "123456789" is reversed to "987656789" using them.

Answer (score 2):

@Rook's answer works for odd length of string too? Anyway here's my attempt, inspired by his answer which takes into account trailing blanks too:

```
    ! Reverse the string
    function reverse_string(string) result(gnirts)

        character(len=*) :: string
        character(len(string)) :: gnirts
        character(1) :: temp
        integer :: i, length

        length = len(string) 

        do i = 1,length
            gnirts(length-i+1:length-i+1) = string(i:i)
        end do

end function reverse_string
```

Comment: `temp` is unused.

Answer (score 2):

Unlike arrays, characters don't have advanced ways of selecting "elements": substrings must be contiguous (which in particular excludes "reverse order").  The approaches of other answers here follow from that: using expressions which individually select length-1 substrings to build up a new string.  An example would be [a simple loop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54382113/3157076) selecting matching substrings.

If we construct an array from individual substrings we can use [`transfer`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54385194/3157076) to put the re-ordered elements back as a string.

Similar to an array constructor implied loop we can use an I/O implied loop with internal write:

```
implicit none

character(*), parameter :: string = 'abcde'
character(len(string))  :: reverse
integer i

write(reverse,'(*(A))') (string(i:i),i=len(string),1,-1)

write(*,'(A)') string, reverse

end
```

This approach, however, cannot be used "in-place" (unlike the `transfer` one) as the internal file cannot appear in the I/O output item list.  An intermediate variable could be used.